# Exception thrown error. Can you point me at what this means and how to correct it

Tags: c++

I'm getting (in visual Studio) an "exception thrown" error say " Access violation writing location 0x00000008."

Part of the code while local debugging that it stops is) 
(temp-> next_ = null ptr)

```
void LinkedList::AddLinkToBack(void* ptr) {


Node *temp = new Node;
temp = LinkedList::first_;

temp->next_ = nullptr;
temp->data_ = ptr;

if (listLen_ = 0) {

    LinkedList::first_ = temp;
    }

else if (listLen_ = 1) {

    first_->next_ = temp;
    LinkedList::last_ = temp;
    temp->prev_ = first_;
}

else {

    for (int i = 0; i <= listLen_; i++) {

        temp = temp->next_;

        if (i = listLen_) {

            LinkedList::last_ = temp;
        }

    }

    temp->next_->prev_ = temp;

}

listLen_ = listLen_ + 1;

}
```

My class looks like

```
struct Node
{
void* data_;
Node* prev_;
Node* next_;

Node()
{
    data_ = 0;
    prev_ = 0;
    next_ = 0;
}
};

class LinkedList
{
private:
Node* first_;
Node* last_;
long listLen_;

public:
LinkedList();
~LinkedList();
void AddLinkToBack(void* ptr);
void* RemoveThisLink(Node* node);
void* RemoveLinkFromFront();
Node* GetFirstNode();
long GetListLength();
};
```

I can add any info if needed.

I have googled this issue and can't find any help. I can only guess that either I'm not allowed to set temp->next equal to null ptr or the program is having a hard time accessing that variable.

Comment: `Node *temp = new Node; temp = LinkedList::first_;` - What's the rationale for instantiating an object, and then throwing away the only pointer to it?

Comment: The point (which clearly looks to be wrong) is that I wanted it equal to head (start of linked list) so that I could use it to loop through the linked list.

Comment: There's more mistakes than correct lines in in this function

Answer (score 0):

Location 0x00000008 is very near to zero. This usually means that you tried to access a member of a class, but a pointer to the object equals zero. (member of a class is at offset 8 within a class, which probably means there are two other members before it of size 4, since most members take 4 bytes).

Accessing a member through a zero pointer is an "Undefined Behavior", which means that at this point a program can do anything, including spontaneously combusting the comp, but in this case it actually assumes there's an object at address zero, and tries to access it.

In your case `temp == nullptr`, so accessing `temp->next` must not be done if you want your program to live. And this means `LinkedList::first_ == nullptr`. I think you need a special handling of this special case.

Comment: *"most members take 4 bytes"* - You have a reference for that?

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like LinkedList::AddLinkToBack is responsible for creating the first node also.

So for the first time, when you call this function, LinkedList::first_ can contain any garbage value (or) zero if you have initialized it so..

for first element in your list

```
Node *temp = new Node;
temp = LinkedList::first_;
```

temp will contain garbage, and note you are leaking memory here the new Node you constructed is no more reachable and is leaked...

So further when you de-reference it saying temp->next = nullptr, you are crashing.